# Insert the selected data from the grid into SQL Server database

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax, web-development-server

I am trying to create a website using Django, python and sql server which lists out the items in a tabular form. And upon selection of particular item via check box i want to update my database table with selected items.

For eg: in the image below if ID : n1234 is selected i want to update backend table with drugsdispensed

[image]

I am trying to learn Django and Python.

Comment: In SO you're supposed to try to do it yourself first. If you have already tried, please include your best effort so far, so people can help to check what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

HTML File :

[image]

loop through the object and save it in the database :
[image]

I know there is a better of doing the same thing looking for comments